# python pandas read_csv taking forever

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I'm trying to load a 128MB file using panda (after googling I found that it's faster than open or np.loadtxt). The file has 1000 lines, each one containing 65K values that are either 0 or 1 separated by a single space.

For some reason it's taking ages and I can't figure out why. 128MB sounds fairly small for me and Matlab loads it in a about a minute.

Here is my (simple) code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

DATA_DIR='D:\BinaryDescriptors3\ORBLearningIntermediatResults2'
TEST_DIR='yosemite_harris'
OUT_DIR='D:\BinaryDescriptors3\ORBLearningTripletsFinalResults'
PATCH_NUM=1000

data_filename=TEST_DIR+'_' + str(PATCH_NUM) + '_ORBresfile.txt'

data_filepath = os.path.join(DATA_DIR,data_filename)

s=time.time()
print "START"
data =  pd.read_csv(data_filepath,delimiter=' ')

e=time.time()

print e-s
```

It never reached the last line (I gave it 30 minutes before terminating it). Why is reading a small, 128MB file taking so long?

EDIT:

1. When trying to read only one line using the following command:

   data =  pd.read_csv(data_filepath,delimiter=' ', nrows=1)

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.7.1.201409021729\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 2090, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.7.1.201409021729\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1547, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "D:\BinaryDescriptors3\Python\LearnTripletsOrb\LearnTripletsOrb.py", line 18, in <module>
    data =  pd.read_csv(data_filepath,delimiter=' ', nrows=1)
  File "C:\Users\GilLevi\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 443, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\GilLevi\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 231, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\GilLevi\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 686, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\GilLevi\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1130, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "parser.pyx", line 727, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:7146)
  File "parser.pyx", line 774, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:7707)
StopIteration
```

2. When trying to read a similar file that contains only one line of 65K characters, I also get the following error:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.7.1.201409021729\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 2090, in 
       debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
   File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.7.1.201409021729\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1547, in run
       pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
   File "D:\BinaryDescriptors3\Python\LearnTripletsOrb\LearnTripletsOrb.py", line 20, in 
       data =  pd.read_csv(data_filepath,delimiter=' ', nrows=1)
   File "C:\Users\GilLevi\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 443, in parser_f
       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

   File "C:\Users\GilLevi\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 231, in _read
       return parser.read(nrows)
     File "C:\Users\GilLevi\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 686, in read
       ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
     File "C:\Users\GilLevi\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1130, in read
       data = self._reader.read(nrows)
     File "parser.pyx", line 727, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:7146)
     File "parser.pyx", line 774, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:7707)
   StopIteration
3. I also trying to produce a similar file that contains 2 lines of 65K but uses "," as a delimiter, and got the same error as in 1 and 2.
4. If load_csv is not the correct approach, can you please recommend a suitable alternative?

Comment: Have you tried it on a smaller file, say just 1 line?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the data, you might try another approach; the format you describe doesn't sound like a typical CSV.

Comment: how long does it take to read a single row? : `data =  pd.read_csv(data_filepath,delimiter=' ', nrows=1)`

Comment: can you just post the first few lines of the data?

Comment: It sounds like a single line is going to have 130,000 characters and 65,000 fields...

Comment: @AndyHayden, every line of the data contains 65K values that are either 0 or 1. I can't really post here 65K values.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using numpy and a BINARY load (because you know exactly the number of bytes per line), e.g., np.fromfile or multiple np.fromstring on each line.

Comment: @GilLevi how's about coming up with a toy example instead, first few rows first few columns (does that also fail?)

Comment: @AndyHayden, I tried a toy example and it does work, I guess that the original file is too big (though 128MB sounds very small to me)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @mdurant, I tried np.fromstring, it also takes ages

Comment: Strange, I created a test file with two rows of 100,000 zeros seperated by a space, and `pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep=" ", header=None)` reads it in a bit less than 5 seconds. But, `np.fromfile` does it in less than 0.1 s.

Answer (score 6):

The question is old but I hope others might find the answer useful.
Pandas (less so NumPy) is optimized (and very good) at working with data that has **plenty** of rows and **a limited number** of columns (say, a few dozen tops). Your case seems to be the opposite so it is not the right tool for the task.
I would preprocess the data before loading it into a DataFrame and I would swap columns and rows in the DataFrame for further processing. So it goes something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[i for i in range(len(txt))])
txt = open(data_filepath).readlines()
for i, ln in enumerate(txt):
  row_items = ln.split()
  df[i] = row_items
...
```

I believe this is going to be quite fast...